# Too large a number - How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

CS0266 ERROR
The num 3 code is working, but the num 4 code isnt... I think the number is too big... How can I fix it?

```
        {
            GameManager.multiplier += 20000000;
            GameManager.o2 -= 2000000000;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("o2", GameManager.o2);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("multiplier", GameManager.multiplier);
        }
        if (num == 4 && GameManager.o2 >= 5000000000)
        {
            GameManager.multiplier += 90000000;
            GameManager.o2 -= 5000000000;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("o2", GameManager.o2);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("multiplier", GameManager.multiplier);
        }
```

Comment: is  `num 4` of type `Int32`? then the may be exceeding the value it can hold. you can use `int.MaxValue` to see the maximum value an Int32 can hold which is 2147483647. if u need integers to hold larger values you can use `Int64` or `long`

Comment: uint is 32 bits, 2 ^ 32 = 4294967296 which is greater than 5000000000. You need to make is a long or ulong to take the width upto 64bits.

Comment: Can you write the code?

Comment: Is your code C# or UnityScript? Please tell us which of these languages you're using, as you have currently indicated your code is both C# and UnityScript, which doesn't make sense because they are distinct languages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Comment: Don't change your complete question, please. Ask a new one instead. I rolled back.

Comment: I cnaged it because it was a stupid qustion. But that time, i was so beginner. I just didnt delete it. But sorry, okay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to change the type of the  `GameManager.o2` to `long`

example:

```
public class GameManager{

public long o2 {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236628/discussion-on-answer-by-thanzeel-too-large-a-number-how-can-i-fix-it).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a datatype that is big enough to store the number. If you are unsure how big your integer number will get, I recommend using [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger).

Comment: Can you help me? Can you write the correct code?